# Access data after API call using Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, github-api

I need to get the data after ajax function request succeed , the data i need to return :

```
{
  "total_count": 391,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "login": "pascalfares",
      "id": 1664478,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1664478?v=3",
}
```

my code is:

```
 $.ajax({    
    url: 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + $('#search').val(),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
         // foreach to get the data 
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the problem. you do not now how to iterate in the foreach? Do you receive "data" object back from ajax success?

Comment: yes i receive data object back i just get [object object]..but i need to get login and id ..etc

Comment: my data like this    {   "total_count": 391,
                                   "incomplete_results": false,
                                "items": [
                             {
                                         "login": "pascalfares",
                             } i need to print pascalfares

Comment: check my answer. You can see how to iterate over your items list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `console.log(data)` in success function and view result in browser console .
this API returned two object : data and meta.
try this

```
success: function(data) {
      for(var i = 0; i< data.data.items.length; i++){
         var login =data.data.items[i].login;
          var id = data.data.items[i].id;
          console.log("ID = " +id + " Login = " + login);
      }
}
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){

      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + $('#search').val(),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(data) {
       for(var i = 0; i< data.data.items.length; i++){
         var login = data.data.items[i].login;
         var id=data.data.items[i].id;
         $('#list').append("<li> Login :" +login+" | Id:"+id+"</li>");
      }
    }
  });
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="#search" />
  <button id="btn" >clck</button> 
<br/><br/>
<ul id="list">
  </ul>
```

*`console.log`  logs a message to a debugging console.*

Comment: @ Mohammad Javad the problem solved :) <input id="#search" /> its must be <input id="search" />... thnx to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following snippet:

```
$.ajax({

url: 'https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fares',
dataType: 'json',
type: 'GET',
success: function(data) {
for(var i = 0; i< data.items.length; i++){
         var login = data.items[i].login;
          var id = data.items[i].id;
          console.log("ID = " +id + " Login = " + login);
      }
}
});
```

Comment: its return nothing...https://api.github.com/search/users?q=fares  this is the data, i need to return login and id from items

Comment: its weird becouse your code dont return me anything..i switch console.log with alert but still return nothing .. this is my full code in this website : http://codepen.io/faresalkhwaja/pen/ozvYQE    see it if you like :)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/3yotgujc/ 
For some reason it just can't querying `string` but it can querying `numbers`?